# Public enum with Internal raw value in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, enums, swift2

I want to create a class with a public enum (to be used by other modules) with an internal String raw value (I don't want other modules to read the raw Value, but I do want to read it internally inside the same module).

I know I can just create another private function that receives the enum and returns a String but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible, I tried doing like this first:

```
public enum Emotion {
    case Hate = EmotionInner.Hate, Love = EmotionInner.Love
}
internal enum EmotionInner: String {
    case Hate = "hate", Love = "love"
}
```

But it won't compile.
Your enums at least should be the same type - so if you want to has `rawValue()` it will has it in both enum. And you can't make `rawValue()` smth like `final` or `static`.

By the way, maybe it's not bad way to make a function for it?